# Java 8 default methods, JAXB, and JavaFX Property frustrations

Tags: java, xml, javafx, jaxb

Is there any way to use JAXB annotations on default methods inherited from Java 8 interfaces?

I created a sample maven project at https://github.com/ruckc/jaxb-java8-javafx highlighting the shims required for what I would like to do.

In dealing with JavaFX properties, i've found that I can use the default methods on interfaces to remove the annoying getters/setters from the data object.

```java
public interface Named {
    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    default String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    default void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().set(name);
    }

    StringProperty nameProperty();
}
```

This removes alot of redundant code inside the implementations.  My issue is that now, when trying to marshall the objects using JAXB, I still have to implement the methods (annotated with `@Shim`) in the implementations, so that the annotations are picked up.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="business")
public class Business implements Named {

    private final StringProperty nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

    @Shim
    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        Named.super.setName(name);
    }

    @Shim
    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return Named.super.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return nameProperty;
    }
}
```

In short, if I remove the `@Shim` the printed out xml from the `main` method doesn't contain the name attribute, and the printed out name attribute from the unmarshalled string is null.  I'd really like avoiding spurious/duplicate code.